# Rich:Layout is not tagged

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss6.x

i am working with JBoss AS 6, Richfaces 4, and JSF 2.0.

i developped a simple xhtml page to define my layouts

here it is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

   <rich:layout>
  <rich:layoutPanel position="top">
    Top
  </rich:layoutPanel>
  <rich:layoutPanel position="right">
    Right
  </rich:layoutPanel>
  <rich:layoutPanel position="center">
       Center
  </rich:layoutPanel>
  <rich:layoutPanel position="left">
       Left
  </rich:layoutPanel>
  <rich:layoutPanel position="bottom">
    Bottom
  </rich:layoutPanel>
</rich:layout>
</ui:composition>
```

I've add these jars on my build path:

```
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.1.0.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.1.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.1.0.Final.jar
guava-r09.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
sac-1.3.jar
```

but unfortunetely when I publish i receive this error :

```
19:37:11,557 ERROR [STDERR] javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /menu.xhtml @11,17 <rich:layout> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: layout
19:37:11,558 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:289)
19:37:11,558 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:228)
19:37:11,558 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,558 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,558 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,558 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,558 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,558 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:388)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:364)
19:37:11,559 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:122)
19:37:11,560 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:294)
19:37:11,560 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:89)
19:37:11,560 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:159)
19:37:11,560 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:157)
19:37:11,560 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:79)
19:37:11,560 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:74)
19:37:11,560 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:95)
19:37:11,560 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
19:37:11,561 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
19:37:11,561 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:110)
19:37:11,561 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:115)
19:37:11,561 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:58)
19:37:11,561 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:245)
19:37:11,561 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:190)
19:37:11,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:731)
19:37:11,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:96)
19:37:11,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
19:37:11,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
19:37:11,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
19:37:11,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
19:37:11,562 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
19:37:11,563 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
19:37:11,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
19:37:11,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
19:37:11,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
19:37:11,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
19:37:11,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
19:37:11,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
19:37:11,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
19:37:11,564 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Please could you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RichFaces 4 has removed support for rich:layout

> having large experinece with 3.3.x users opinions could only say that those components has lower priority because our previous layouts were not used much. Users still preferred to use plain Y! or jQuery(to get more control). So that's why postponed and want to revise to make more convenient/rich.

See [this](https://community.jboss.org/message/598688#598688)